# Wordpress posts with multiple images

Tags: slider, wordpress, custom-fields

I making a website in wordpress and I am adding some posts in it.
I am trying to make like this http://www.webmd.com/allergies/ss/slideshow-nasal-irrigation
I can add multiple text from custome fields but I am not able to to add different images with each custom field.
Can anyone give me idea about this. That how i can add images with these slides. Should I use the custom fileds or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use install Simple field plugin.   https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fields/

In this plugin you can create Fields you can add as many images, text fields, textareas, or any other field type, as you want to to a post.